# How to use Windsor Castle Logging Facitlity for .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, logging, castle-windsor, nuget

I'm very interested in using Windsor Castle Logging Facitlity for my .NET 3.5 app but the version on Nuget is for .NET 4.5: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.LoggingFacility

The Castle Windsor version that I'm currently using is 2.5 and I can't upgrade it.

More info: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx

Where can I download the Windsor Castle Logging Facitlity for .NET 3.5 that works with Castle Windsor 2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Castle.LoggingFacility actually supports .NET 3.5: just look at the package structure.

[image: Castle.LoggingFacility package structure]

It depends on Castle Windsor 3.0 or greater so you can't reference it via NuGet unless you upgrade CW to that minimum version.

BTW the package contains just two classes and an enum so I think it is quite easy to just download the source code and recompile it.